# Paste formatted text from Word to PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, copy-paste

I am copying some formatted text in Word and paste it into PowerPoint. It is pasted as an image instead of text. When I change to "Paste as text", the formatting gets lost.

My text is

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

return MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
  supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
```

with syntax highlighting:

[image: Text to be copied]

As long as the PowerPoint slide is completely empty, pasting works. Once it has some content, the new text gets pasted in a new container at the top of the slide

[image: Text pasted in PowerPoint]

How can I paste a second formatted text into the same textbox of one slide?

Comment: Have you chosen to paste with source or destination theme?

Comment: Click within the text box, press Enter if you need to start a new line, then paste the next batch of text.